# HP Proliant DL360 G9 with Samsung 983 DCT

Tags: hp-proliant, ssd, u.2

I have a HP Proliant DL360 G9 (with P440ar storage controller). I would like to know whether it is possible to connect NVMe U.2 SSD? The SSD I was thinking about is Samsung 983 DCT.

I'm not sure how to determine whether the controller supports U.2. It only specifies that it supports SAS/SATA, and that is has a PCI Express Gen3 x 8 link.

Another thing - does the controller determine the backplane connectors? Or are those two separate items?

Comment: You may have an issue with the controller accepting a non HP storage device.  Even if HP uses the same basic hardware, the firmware may unique and the controller will require HP firmware to function with that storage device

Comment: Do you *need* to use U.2 drives? That requires the NVMe enablement kit for the HPE server.

Answer (score 1):

The HPE Proliant DL360 gen9 will accept NVMe devices with the addition of an `HPE DL360 Gen9 NVMe 2 Solid State Drive Express Bay Enablement Kit` (p/n 764628-B21) or the `HPE DL360 Gen9 6 NVMe + 4 SAS/SATA Express Bay Enablement Kit` (p/n 817676-B21). This provides support for up to 2 or 6 NVMe SFF drives ([HPE reference](https://h20195.www2.hpe.com/v2/getdocument.aspx?docname=c04375623)).

At time of writing there are currently eight HPE NVMe parts listed as compatible with this server, for instance the `HPE 2TB NVMe x4 Lanes Read Intensive SFF (2.5in) SCN  SSD` (p/n 877986-B21). These are described as having interface "NVMe" with no mention of U.2 or any other established physical interface. I interpret this to mean that the interface with the server is via the enablement kit which is a PCI x4 3.0 card. This is *not* U.2 and I can see no evidence that the gen9 supports U.2.

I would suggest that NVMe using an add-in card (AIC) would be a good option. Any standards-based PCI AIC could be used.